# SQL select N rows from 5 differents id

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I got a little question.

I would like to select N rows from 5 id.

I already tried this request :

```
SELECT a.fk_produit_id, a.id, a.titre, a.prix, a.description, a.short_description, a.image_url 
from produits p, articles a 
WHERE p.id = a.fk_produit_id AND p.fk_category_id IN (2, 248, 335, 493, 1038) 
GROUP BY p.fk_category_id;
```

Or this one :

```
SELECT a.fk_produit_id, a.id, a.titre, a.prix 
from articles a 
inner join produits p 
WHERE p.id = a.fk_produit_id AND p.fk_category_id IN (2, 248, 335, 493, 1038) 
order by a.fk_produit_id limit 5
```

I would like that the result be like this :

```
id: 1 : -> record 1
          -> record 1
          -> record 1
          -> record 1
          -> record 1
id: 2 : -> record 2
          -> record 2
          -> record 2
          -> record 2
          -> record 2
id: 3 : -> record 3
          -> record 3
          -> record 3
          -> record 3
          -> record 3

id: 4 : -> record 4
          -> record 4
          -> record 4
          -> record 4
          -> record 4
id: 5 : -> record 5
          -> record 5
          -> record 5
          -> record 5
          -> record 5
```

But they didn't work as i want.
If someone coul help me or explain how can I solve it.
Thanks you in advance guys I continue my research by my side.

Comment: Please provide tables structure test data and desired result [mre]

Comment: Do you want 5 articles per product, or 5 products per article?

Comment: I would like 5 articles by products categories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved by using [`ROW_NUMBER()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_row-number)

```
SELECT  a.fk_produit_id, 
        a.id, 
        a.titre, 
        a.prix, 
        a.description, 
        a.short_description, 
        a.image_url
FROM    (   SELECT  a.fk_produit_id, 
                    a.id, 
                    a.titre, 
                    a.prix, 
                    a.description, 
                    a.short_description, 
                    a.image_url,
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY p.fk_category_id 
                                      ORDER BY a.fk_produit_id) AS RowNumber
            FROM    produits AS p
                    INNER JOIN articles AS a
                        ON p.id = a.fk_produit_id
            WHERE   p.fk_category_id IN (2, 248, 335, 493, 1038)
                
        ) AS a
WHERE   a.RowNumber <= 5; -- Change 5 to whatever "n" is
```

You may need to alter your ordering as required, but this should get you started

Comment: That's not rly doesn't work as I want. Normally I would like to display 25 records ( 5 records x 5 id ). But this request select 9000+ records.

Comment: Without any proper sample data it is hard to see why this is not working as expected. I've put together a [simplified example that does only return 25 rows](https://dbfiddle.uk/tLw6tbPS), have you perhaps missed out the final where clause? or do you have other conditions (such as an OR) in your where that could be impacting the results?

Comment: I edit and add some examples of the table. Tell me if you need something else. Thans you for your help !

Comment: Can you post some sample data that is relevant to your issue please? With your sample data the initial query you posted (excluding limit and grouping) only returns 5 results, so it is hard to use this data to visualise the issue you are having. https://dbfiddle.uk/JcC5JNgm

Comment: I add some picture of my database. The first one is the "articles" table and the second one the "produits" table. Tell me if you need something else

Comment: [Images of code/data](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) is not that useful. Are you able to create a fiddle (a bit like the ones I have linked to) that contains data that demonstrates the actual issue you are having? It doesn't have to be actual data, or your full database, just enough data to demonstrate the problem. Based on what you have posted there is no reason the query I have posted, or the one Jarlh has posted would not work, so there must be something you are not telling us about your query or your data

Comment: What we ideally need is a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your problem, that can be used to test and demonstrate any potential solutions

Comment: It's fine I used your code and modified it and I found the solution of my problem. Thanks you so much I can finally move forward. :)

Answer (score -1):

You can use a *lateral derived table* to return 5 articles per product:

```
SELECT p.*, a.fk_produit_id, a.id, a.titre, a.prix 
from produits p
cross join
    lateral (select * from articles
             WHERE p.id = fk_produit_id
             order by fk_produit_id
             limit 5) a
where p.fk_category_id IN (2, 248, 335, 493, 1038)
```